# How can I increase the width of the div by 10% on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

e.g. 200px to 220px. Apparently "+=10%" doesn't work as I expected. Here is my code http://bit.ly/Wyhe32

Comment: It seems to be working on IE9. What is your expectation? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want to animate or just set the value on hover. Here is both.

### Animation

```
$(".gds").css({
    'backgroundColor': '#DBEAF9'
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: $(this).width()*1.1
    }, 350).addClass('shadow');
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: ($(this).width()/110)*100
    }, 350).removeClass('shadow');
});​
```

### Simple CSS property change

```
$(".gds").css({
    'backgroundColor': '#DBEAF9'
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).css('width', $(this).width()*1.1)+'px';
}, function () {
    $(this).css('width', (($(this).width()/110)*100)+'px')
    }, 350).removeClass('shadow');
});​
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user1759608 You can thank him by marking this as the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Get the width of the element and apply it to the css property Width:

```
$('.divclass').css('width',$('.divclass').width() + ((parseFloat($('.divclass').width())) / 100) * 10) + "px");
```

Comment: Did you check his code? He is not doing it like that. That's why the other person deleted his answer, which is similar to yours.

Comment: @AlexR. He can still apply the width using this

Comment: Well, if he doesn't want animation, then it could work. But check his code first and try to understand what his objective is before answering. Just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the beginning of your hover function :

```
var newWidth = (parseFloat($('.gds').width()) * 1.1);
```

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/rKT2p/

Answer (score 0):

```
width:$(this).width()*1.1
```

does exactly what I wished for. Thank you, [davidpfahler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318117/davidpfahler)